# EF core Raw SQL (FromSql) query returning incorrect data?

Tags: entity-framework-core, sql-server-2016

I'm confused because of query which is returning different data for only one column when using a raw SQL query from Entity Framework (see the screenshot below).

The correct result is of course the one I get when querying the database directly from SQL Server.

Certainly, I'm executing exactly the same query, on the same database and on the same server. And I'm looking for the same columns.

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the LigneFacture class:

```
    public class LigneFacture
{
    [Required]
    public string Entite { get; set; }
    public decimal NumFacture { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2)]
    public string TypeTransaction { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateFacture { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CodeClient { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string NomClient { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CodeProduit { get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string NomProduit { get; set; }
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string CodeLabo{ get; set; }
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Laboratoire { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(25)]
    public string Numlot { get; set; }
    public DateTime Peremption { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantite { get; set; }
    public decimal ValeurHt { get; set; }
    public decimal ValeurRz { get; set; }
    public decimal ValeurTva { get; set; }
    public decimal PuAchat { get; set; }
    public decimal PuPpa { get; set; }
    public decimal PuDemi { get; set; }
    public decimal PuCess { get; set; }

    //This field is causing the problem (it's declared as int in the database as well)
    public int Ligne { get; set; } 

    public string HreString { get; set; }
    public int AnneeTransaction { get; set; }
    public int MoisTransaction { get; set; }
    public decimal TauxRemise { get; set; }
    public string Zone { get; set; }
    public int Colis { get; set; }

}
```

The rest of the values is exactly the same.

Comment: What is `LigneFacture` - a fake entity class? Can we see it?

Comment: Yes, it's a fake entity class.

Comment: What is the PK of that "entity" (I don't see it defined)?

Comment: It's defined in the model builder. But you've got a point here because two  rows of three have got the same key (from a business POV) so I think it's returning the values of the first one.

Comment: It's typical for all EF versions when mapping to db view. You have to define some fake PK (either rownumber or composte including one or more columns which combination is unique in the result set).

Comment: Yes i think it creates an index based on the defined PK of the entity, then it queries based on that index (all the rows with the same PK are related to that one index). Thanks for help i'll add an answer to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ivan Stoev pointed out it seems to be related the primary key of the entity being queried on.

Two rows out of three have only one different column value but the exact same primary key so it seems like the first one is returned twice.